# python/MySQL Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql

I know this problem has been raised many times, and I was looking for an answer, but every solution did not work for me. I was trying add `'` in multiple places, change form of code but nothing.
If I paste the command into SQL (with random data) in phpMyAdmin then it's working.

This is the part of my code, but if I run the code I have an error: `Unknown column 'title' in 'field list'`

```
sel = f"(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE cId = {kpi})"
connection.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table2(shpId,nr,title,category,on,active,date)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,now())", (sel,i,title,category[k],1,1))
```

Has anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does `table2` definitely have a `title` column?

Comment: Yes, as i wrote: If I paste the command into SQL (with random data) in phpMyAdmin then it's working.

Comment: And is phpMyAdmin definitely working on the same db and schema as your Python code?

Comment: you can't use a `sel`ect query as a parameter to a `INSERT` query. Use values only. Use [INSERT ... SELECT ... ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: khelwood - yes, because i was print db command to terminal before execute and then i used it in phpMyAdmin